# MYSQL insert into table select id as NULL, * from temp_tbl

Tags: mysql

I would like to select everything from a temporary table then set the id of the result to NULL so that I can insert this record to a table like below:

```
insert into product select NULL as id, * from tmp_tb
```

But this query does not work. Please give me an idea how to do this correctly.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the `id` is treated as `NULL`? Can you explain? Also post the `create table code` of the above tables. Thank you

Comment: because I want to insert the result of query to a table. I created the temporary table from product table then I dropped the ID of that temp table. I am like duplicating the whole content of product table.

Comment: Isn't the `ID` field in `product` table is `AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`? It would be better if you post the `create table code` of both of the tables.

Comment: @bananaCute share schema for both tables `product` and `tmp_tb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
INSERT INTO product SELECT NULL, tmp_tb.* FROM tmp_tb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into product select NULL, col2, col3, ..., colN from tmp_tb
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, Thanks for your reply. This will work but I was hoping that there's a way to no longer enumerate all the fields because there's about 20 of them.

Comment: @bananaCute If you use `*` it will return all fields; and columns count mismatches;